# Existence of solutions for general nonlinear system of equations

Tags: polynomials, nonlinear-system

Let us assume the following $2\times 2$ system of nonlinear equations
$$\begin{split}
f_1(x,y)\cdot x+f_2(x,y)\cdot y=f_3(x,y)\\
g_1(x,y)\cdot x+g_2(x,y)\cdot y=g_3(x,y)\
\end{split}$$
for the real variables $x,y$. The functions $f_i,g_i$ are general real polynomials of the form $$f_i,g_i\sim\sum_{n=0}^Nc_nx^{n}y^{N-n}$$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I was wondering the following:

1. Is there a general method of determining whether or not there exist real solutions for this problem?
   I read somewhere about Hilbert's Nullstellensatz method but I am not able to understand how it applies in this simple setting (or if it is at all relevant).
2. If such a method exists and applies here, does it still work when we choose the polynomials to be of infinite degree? Could I assume that they are special functions, e.g. square roots or exponentials, or they have to be polynomials of finite degree?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks a lot for your comment. As far as I understand, the resultant exists only for polynomials of finite degree. What happens if I let $N\to \infty$?

Comment: I have no idea. As long as $N$ is finite, we can view this as a system of two polynomial equations and solve it. But what happens for $N\to \infty$? Are we dealing with formal power series?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that these $f_i$ and $g_i$ could be, for example, root or exponential functions. These can be written as a polynomial of infinite degree with very specific coefficients.